# How can I prove that if $2^x+1$ is prime, then $x$ is a power of $2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove that if $2^x+1$ is prime, then $x$ is a power of $2$? Can someone help me prove this?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot a $+1$ It's edited now

Comment: Not equivalent. $2^{2^x}=4^{2^{x-1}}$

Comment: You probably meant to ask about $2^x + 1$ - if that's prime then $x$ is a power of two.

Comment: Not the same.  $2^{2x} = 4^x$ and this is very different from $2^{2^x}$.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker: Yea you're right... Going to etdit it now

Comment: Not true! The first calculation with $x=3$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Why did you post two almost identical questions?

Comment: @Piquito Since when has $9$ been a prime?

Comment: @Ross Milikan; I tried to delete the other one because it was really wrong... I didn't do the job better this time...

Comment: I never stop being surprised how triggerhappy people are here to jump in and answer questions that obviously have typos / are super-easily shown to be false. It would be much better if people gave OP some minuttes to clarify and comments are here exactly for this purpose: for asking for clarifications.

Comment: @Winther The same could be said for people too trigger-happy to edit their questions before posting.

Comment: @Winther, people often ask questions here that are "super-easily" shown to be false.  Super easy for us $\ne$ super easy for them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. You can probably show that 
$$
A-B \text{ divides } A^n - B^n .
$$

Then try to show that
$$
A+B \text{ divides } A^n + B^n  
$$
when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.  $2^{2^3}+1=2^8+1=257$ is prime.  The theorem you are trying to quote is if $2^x+1$ is prime then $x$ is a power of $2$.  Here, if $x$ has an odd factor $a$, $2^a+1$ divides $2^x+1$

Comment: Yea... I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Write $x = 2^l n$, where $n$ is odd. We have

$$2^x + 1 = (2^{2^l})^n + 1 = (2^{2^l} + 1)(2^{2^l(n-1)} - \cdots  + 1).$$

Since $2^x + 1$ is prime, then the above factorization implies $n = 1$.